# Swift: didBeginContact() is not called after reloading level

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to the swift language and I'm having a bit of an issue. I'm guessing its a simple mistake, but regardless I cannot seem to find the issue. I'm making a game. After you lose, I create a replay button on the screen. Once clicked I begin resetting the game.

I essentially reset all values, remove all children, and reinitialize. It reinitializes fine - all the backgrounds and sprites are moving correctly, but if I touch spikes (the losing mechanic of the game) the game does not end; the didBeginContact function is not being called to enact the losing portion of the code again. I'm guessing it has something to do with the collisionBitMasks and categoryBitMasks.

Neither the contact between the player and spikes, nor the contact between the player and platforms (to keep score) is working at all.

Note: My code is messy at the moment. I would like to get it working before I start an overhaul to make it pretty and optimized.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
//...
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == spikeGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == playerGroup {
    gameOver = true
    movingObjectsNode.speed = 0
    //...

    rplay.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
    rplay.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    rplay.setTitle("Replay", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    rplay.addTarget(self, action: "rplayAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(rplay)
} else if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == playerGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == platformGroup {
    var contactedPlatform = contact.bodyB.node
    contactHistory.append(contactedPlatform!)
    if contactHistory.count >= 3 {
        contactHistory.removeAtIndex(0)
    }
    if contactHistory.count > 1 {
        if contactHistory[0].name != contactHistory[1].name {
            score = score + 1
            scoreLabel.text = String(score)
        }
    } else {
        score = score + 1
        scoreLabel.text = String(score)
    }
}
func rplayAction() {
    rplay.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeAllChildren()

    bgOnArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    platformHistArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    platformOnScreenArrayB.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    platformOnScreenArrayW.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    movingObjectsNode.removeAllChildren()
    gameOverTabHolderNode.removeAllChildren()
    pW.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    pB.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    pWMask.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    pBMask.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    contactHistory.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    state = true
    gstate = false
    allowContact = true
    gameOver = false
    score = 0
    count = 0
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    scoreLabelArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    movingObjectsNode.speed = 1

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -20)
    self.addChild(movingObjectsNode)

    var bgWTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bgW")
    var bgBTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bgB")
    var playerBTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/playerB")
    var playerWTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/playerW")

    var movebg = SKAction.moveByX(-bgWTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 10.0) //4.48 = 20 pixels a sec?
    var replacebg = SKAction.moveByX(bgWTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    var movebgForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movebg, replacebg]))

    makeBackground()

    //note: for some reason spikes take forever to load (because of the tempFloatPoint was condensed into one line)
    for var i:CGFloat=0; i<36; i++ {
        var floorSpikes = SKShapeNode()
        var tempInt = Int(i)
        var tempString = String(tempInt)
        var tempFloatPoint = CGFloat()
        var path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, bg.size.width/14 , 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, bg.size.width/28, bg.size.height/9)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
        floorSpikes.path = path
        floorSpikes.lineWidth = 0;
        floorSpikes.name = "2 " + tempString
        tempFloatPoint = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
        tempFloatPoint = tempFloatPoint - (bg.size.width/7)
        tempFloatPoint = tempFloatPoint + (bg.size.width/14 * i)

        if i <= 7 {
            floorSpikes.position = CGPoint(x: tempFloatPoint, y: 0)
        } else if i > 7 && i <= 20 {
            floorSpikes.position = CGPoint(x: tempFloatPoint - 5, y: 0)
        } else if i > 20 && i <= 36 {
            floorSpikes.position = CGPoint(x: tempFloatPoint - 10, y: 0)
        }

        floorSpikes.runAction(movebgForever)
        floorSpikes.zPosition = 100
        floorSpikes.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
        floorSpikes.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        floorSpikes.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = spikeGroup
        movingObjectsNode.addChild(floorSpikes)
    }

    for var i:CGFloat=0; i<36; i++ {
        var ceilingSpikes = SKShapeNode()
        var tempInt = Int(i)
        var tempString = String(tempInt)
        var tempFloatPoint = CGFloat()
        var path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, bg.size.width/14 , 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, bg.size.width/28, -bg.size.height/9)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
        ceilingSpikes.path = path
        ceilingSpikes.lineWidth = 0;
        ceilingSpikes.name = "3 " + tempString
        tempFloatPoint = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
        tempFloatPoint = tempFloatPoint - (bg.size.width/7)
        tempFloatPoint = tempFloatPoint + (bg.size.width/14 * i)

        if i <= 7 {
            ceilingSpikes.position = CGPoint(x: tempFloatPoint, y: CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
        } else if i > 7 && i <= 20 {
            ceilingSpikes.position = CGPoint(x: tempFloatPoint - 5, y: CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
        } else if i > 20 && i <= 36 {
            ceilingSpikes.position = CGPoint(x: tempFloatPoint - 10, y: CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
        }

        ceilingSpikes.runAction(movebgForever)
        ceilingSpikes.zPosition = 100
        ceilingSpikes.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
        ceilingSpikes.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        ceilingSpikes.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = spikeGroup
        movingObjectsNode.addChild(ceilingSpikes)
    }

    //player stuff
    player = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerBTexture)

    player.xScale = 0.1
    player.yScale = 0.1
    player.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + self.frame.size.height/8)

    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(player.size.width, player.size.height))
    player.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.0
    player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    player.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0.0
    player.physicsBody!.angularVelocity = 0.0
    player.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = playerGroup
    player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = spikeGroup
    player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = spikeGroup
    player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = platformGroup
    player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = platformGroup

    self.addChild(player)

    var screen = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, self.frame.height)

    scoreLabel.fontName = "GKFont"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
    scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + screen.width/2 - screen.width/10, self.frame.height - self.frame.height/4)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
    scoreLabelArray.append(scoreLabel)

    makeStarterPlatforms()
}
```

I think the issue is in one of these two functions. Thank you in advance for any help you're willing to give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I figured it out. I don't know why, but after replaying the game and reloading everything, the order in which collisions occur is reversed. For each collision statement, I had to change....

```
contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == playerGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == platformGroup
```

To....

```
contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == playerGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == platformGroup || contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == platformGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == playerGroup
```

If someone could clarify why this change needed to be implemented, feel free to comment below.